# Is there a way to check for both `null` and `undefined`?

Tags: typescript, null-check

Since TypeScript is strongly-typed, simply using `if () {}` to check for `null` and `undefined` doesn't sound right.

Does TypeScript have any dedicated function or syntax sugar for this?

Comment: ```Since TypeScript is strongly-typed``` I couldn't find this in it's docs and I have doubts about it...

Comment: Recommend to read up on the latest non-nullable types , this is Typescript 2 , but already in beta as of today.  [Non-nullable types #7140] (https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/7140)

Comment: TypeScript has no dedicated functions to do anything. It's a typing system and a transpiler, not a library.

Comment: As you say it is bad to just check `if () {}` since that will also be true for `0`.

Answer (score 667):

Using a juggling-check, you can test both `null` and `undefined` in one hit:

```
if (x == null) {
```

If you use a strict-check, it will only be true for values set to `null` and won't evaluate as true for undefined variables:

```
if (x === null) {
```

You can try this with various values using this example:

```
var a: number;
var b: number = null;

function check(x, name) {
    if (x == null) {
        console.log(name + ' == null');
    }

    if (x === null) {
        console.log(name + ' === null');
    }

    if (typeof x === 'undefined') {
        console.log(name + ' is undefined');
    }
}

check(a, 'a');
check(b, 'b');
```

Output

> "a == null"
>
> "a is undefined"
>
> "b == null"
>
> "b === null"

Comment: What is "juggling-check"?

Comment: @akapelko it is where the type is juggled (i.e. "can we make this type a boolean"). So an empty string is treated as a boolean false, for example. A common bug when juggling is: `"false" == false` a non-empty string like "false" evaluates to `true`.

Comment: This is due to JS's 'type coercion'.

Comment: Except if x is 0 (and that's a valid value), it will pass your undefined/null test.

Comment: @JonGunter that would be true of truthy/falsey `if(x)` style checks, but not `if(x == null)`, which only catches `null` and `undefined`. Check it using `var c: number = 0; check(c, 'b');` it is not "nully", `null`, or `undefined`.

Comment: Is if(!x) equal to if(x == null)?

Comment: @developer - not quite, as `if (!x)` would treat (for example) the number `0` and the string `''` as null, whereas `if (x == null)` would not.

Comment: How about checking for not null or undefined?  Is `if ( x!= null)` equivalent to `if (!(x != null))`?

Comment: @Fenton I think u meant to say "as falsy" instead of "as null"

Comment: Is there any practical difference between juggling and type coercion? Why do we need two terms?

Comment: @Skrymsli it is only "juggling" when the implicit conversion is likely to surprise the programmer (i.e. you have to drop the ball for it to be juggling).

Comment: You should only use "typeof" if you don't know if a variable is already declared, but this example uses "x" which is declared as a function parameter. So you can just do "x === undefined" instead.

Comment: I believe this is not really a TypeScript thing. This works in Vanilla JS as well. Maybe you could point this out in your answer.

Comment: @Reactgular my test cases cover why that's not the solution.

Comment: @spierala correct, it's just JavaScript.

Answer (score 467):

```
if( value ) {
}
```

will evaluate to `true` if `value` is not:

- `null`
- `undefined`
- `NaN`
- empty string `''`
- `0`
- `false`

typescript includes javascript rules.

Comment: What if value is of boolean type?

Comment: can you combine two variables eg. if(value1 && value2) to check if both of them are undefined ?

Comment: @AkshayrajKore yes you can

Comment: And now, if I wait a number, and I want to check if this number is not null, but let's say it's value is 0; it does not pass the condition check, so how I do this properly with numbers ?

Comment: @Alex if the value==0 returns false

Comment: @RamazanSağır yeah thanks I know that, but the fact is 0 value is something valid that I can have, the only check I want to do is that the variable is neither null or undefined. I have read that I can do it by using val != null (the != instead of !== also checks undefined value)

Comment: @RamazanSağır I just checked with one of my piece of code and "if (undefined)" evaluated to true. This is my object { businessId: "undefined" } look like, then if I check "if (businessId)" it is evaluated to true. :(

Comment: @RamazanSağır I found the reason it's because of double quote surrounding undefined keyword. Otherwise if (undefined) evaluated to false;

Comment: This solution will not work if the tslint rule - "strict-boolean-expressions" is enabled.

Comment: It will evaluate false if value us falsy, as simple as this.

Comment: @counterflow then you need to explicitly check for it: `if (typeof value == 'boolean')`

Answer (score 184):

In **TypeScript 3.7** we have now **Optional chaining**  and **Nullish Coalescing** to check **null** and **undefined** in the same time, example:

```
let x = foo?.bar.baz();
```

this code will check if foo is defined otherwise it will return undefined

**old way** :

```
if(foo != null && foo != undefined) {
   x = foo.bar.baz();
}
```

this:

```
let x = (foo === null || foo === undefined) ? undefined : foo.bar();

if (foo && foo.bar && foo.bar.baz) { // ... }
```

With optional chaining will be:

```
let x = foo?.bar();

if (foo?.bar?.baz) { // ... }
```

another new feature is **Nullish Coalescing**, example:

```
let x = foo ?? bar(); // return foo if it's not null or undefined otherwise calculate bar
```

old way:

```
let x = (foo !== null && foo !== undefined) ?
foo :
bar();
```

**BONUS**
[image]

Comment: This should be the accepted answer now.  Typescript 3.7 also supports "Nullish Coalescing".

    var foo = possibleUndefinedOrNull ?? fallbackValueIfFirstValueIsUndefinedOrNull;

Here is the documentation: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html

Comment: Optional chaining and Nullish Coalescing are great but in case of a single `if` stmt like `if (context != null) word.ctx = context;` one still has to resort to the old juggling-check  as described in the upvoted comment https://stackoverflow.com/a/28984306/407986

Comment: Yes, for almost scenarios, we could we `Optional chaining` , e.g. `if (foo?.bar?.baz)` https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html

Comment: Nullish Coalescing seems not supported in typescript 4.5.4. Is it deprecated?

Comment: Tried const bar = foo ?? 'undefined';  Per Nullish Coalescing, when foo is null or empty, bar should store  'undefined', but I am getting ''. Is it supported in typescript 4.5.4? Via ternary operator it works const bar = foo ? foo : 'undefined';

Comment: NOTE: `if (foo?.bar?.baz) { // ... }` is not a strict null|undefined check as it will be false if `baz` itself is fasley (zero, false, empty dict, empty list, etc)

Answer (score 92):

> Does TypeScript has dedicated function or syntax sugar for this

TypeScript fully understands the JavaScript version which is `something == null`.

TypeScript will correctly rule out both `null` and `undefined` with such checks.

## More

https://basarat.gitbook.io/typescript/recap/null-undefined

Comment: I like doing two equals `myVar == null`. Just another option.

Comment: `== null` is the correct way to test for null & undefined. `!!something` is a useless coercion in a conditional in JS (just use `something`). `!!something` will also coerce 0 and '' to false, which is not what you want to do if you are looking for null/undefined.

Answer (score 46):

I did different tests on the typescript playground:

http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/

```
let a;
let b = null;
let c = "";
var output = "";

if (a == null) output += "a is null or undefined\n";
if (b == null) output += "b is null or undefined\n";
if (c == null) output += "c is null or undefined\n";
if (a != null) output += "a is defined\n";
if (b != null) output += "b is defined\n";
if (c != null) output += "c is defined\n";
if (a) output += "a is defined (2nd method)\n";
if (b) output += "b is defined (2nd method)\n";
if (c) output += "c is defined (2nd method)\n";

console.log(output);
```

gives:

```
a is null or undefined
b is null or undefined
c is defined
```

so:

- checking if (a == null) is right to know if a is null or undefined
- checking if (a != null) is right to know if a is defined
- checking if (a) is wrong to know if a is defined

Comment: Why would you use the TypeScript playground for this? Nothing here has anything to do with TypeScript.

Comment: Because the question was related to Typescript, I was trying to test different  proposed solutions against the Typescript transpiler.

Comment: The TS transpiler would not transform any of this code at all.

Answer (score 43):

#### SIMPLE ANSWER

Although Typescript is a strongly typed language, it has the same problems with pointers and variables initialization inherited from Javascript.
Javascript doesn't check whether a variable exists in the context, the so common `undefined` status.

to evaluate if value **ISN'T** `null`,`undefined`,`0`,`false`,`""`, or `NaN`:

```js
if ( value )
or
if ( !!value )
```

for negative conditional, check if the value is `null`,`undefined`,`0`,`false`,`""`,or `NaN`:

```js
if ( !value )
```

to test if is `null` or `undefined`:

```js
if ( value == null )
```

to test only `null`:

```js
if ( value === null )
```

to test only `undefined`:

```js
if ( value === undefined )
```

---

##### MORE DETAILED ANSWER

**1-** It will evaluate to **true** if value **is not**: `null`, `undefined`, `NaN`, `empty string ''`, `0`, `false`
If the value is `null`,`undefined`,`NaN`,`empty string`,`0`, or `false`, will go to the **else** condition.

```js
if ( value ) {
  console.log('value is something different from 0, "", false, NaN, null, undefined');
} else {
  console.log('value is 0, "", false, NaN, null or undefined');
}
if ( !!value ) {
  console.log('value is something different from 0, "", false, NaN, null, undefined');
} else {
  console.log('value is 0, "", false, NaN, null or undefined');
}
```

**2-** If you want a negative condition, then you'll need to use:

```js
if ( !value ) {
  console.log('value is 0, "", false, NaN, null or undefined');
} else {
  console.log('value is something different from 0, "", false, NaN, null, undefined');
}
```

**3-** It will evaluate if value is `null` or `undefined`

```js
if ( value == null ) {
  console.log('is null or undefined');
} else {
  console.log('it isnt null neither undefined');
}
```

**4-** Using a test with boolean values doesn't work.
It will **NOT** evaluate to **true** neither to **false** if value is `null`, `undefined`, `0`, `empty string`, `NaN`
Both conditions will always go to the **else** condition.
With the exception if value is a boolean variable.

```js
if ( value==true ) {
} else { 
}
if ( value==false ) {
} else { 
}
```

Comment: Do you mean less concise?

Answer (score 42):

You may want to try

```
if(!!someValue)
```

with `!!`.

**Explanation**

The first `!` will turn your expression into a `boolean` value.

Then `!someValue` is `true` if `someValue` is *falsy* and `false` if `someValue` is *truthy*. This might be confusing.

By adding another `!`, the expression is now `true` if `someValue` is *truthy* and `false` if `someValue` is *falsy*, which is much easier to manage.

**Discussion**

Now, why do I bother myself with `if (!!someValue)` when something like `if (someValue)` would have give me the same result?

Because `!!someValue` is precisely a boolean expression, whereas `someValue` could be absolutely anything. This kind of expression will now alow to write functions (and God we need those) like:

```
isSomeValueDefined(): boolean {
  return !!someValue
}
```

instead of:

```
isSomeValueDefined(): boolean {
  if(someValue) {
    return true
  }
  return false
}
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: so, if someValue is 'false'(with string type), then !!someValue is false(boolean type)?

Comment: I guess you may say so.This technic is precisely used to avoid having this kind of confusion. I hope you like it!

Comment: but what confused me is !!'false' equals true. Just because of this case, i can not use this technic.

Comment: `!!'false'` is in deed `true` because `'false'` is a valid string

Comment: so this technic can not cover this case, or is there a workaround solution?

Answer (score 39):

For `Typescript 2.x.x` you should do it in a following way(using [type guard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards)):

**tl;dr**

```
function isDefined<T>(value: T | undefined | null): value is T {
  return <T>value !== undefined && <T>value !== null;
}
```

---

**Why?**

In this way `isDefined()` will respect variable's type and the following code would know take this check in account.

**Example 1** - basic check:

```
function getFoo(foo: string): void { 
  //
}

function getBar(bar: string| undefined) {   
  getFoo(bar); //ERROR: "bar" can be undefined
  if (isDefined(bar)) {
    getFoo(bar); // Ok now, typescript knows that "bar' is defined
  }
}
```

**Example 2** - types respect:

```
function getFoo(foo: string): void { 
  //
}

function getBar(bar: number | undefined) {
  getFoo(bar); // ERROR: "number | undefined" is not assignable to "string"
  if (isDefined(bar)) {
    getFoo(bar); // ERROR: "number" is not assignable to "string", but it's ok - we know it's number
  }
}
```

Comment: I wish they added this as an util function.

Comment: Note that the check for nullish should be defined like this:
```function isNullish<T>(value: T | undefined | null): value is undefined | null {
 return <T>value === undefined || <T>value === null;
}```

Comment: @KfirDadosh is right, isNullish should be used instead, (or call it `isNotDefined` if you like). The problem with the original code is if the type parameter T is `null` or `undefined`, then the original code will return the opposite of the correct answer.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer in 2022

Answer (score 31):

I think this answer needs an update, check the edit history for the old answer.

Basically, you have three deferent cases null, undefined, and undeclared, see the snippet below.

```js
// bad-file.ts
console.log(message)
```

You'll get an error says that variable `message` is undefined (aka undeclared), of course, the Typescript compiler shouldn't let you do that but REALLY nothing can prevent you.

```js
// evil-file.ts
// @ts-gnore
console.log(message)
```

The compiler will be happy to just compile the code above.
So, if you're sure that all variables are declared you can simply do that

```js
if ( message != null ) {
    // do something with the message
}
```

the code above will check for `null` and `undefined`, BUT in case the `message` variable may be undeclared (for safety), you may consider the following code

```js
if ( typeof(message) !== 'undefined' && message !== null ) {
    // message variable is more than safe to be used.
}
```

Note: the order here `typeof(message) !== 'undefined' && message !== null` is very important you have to check for the `undefined` state first atherwise it will be just the same as `message != null`, thanks @Jaider.

Comment: M. Kamal if something = 0, your verification with !something will give you problems.

Comment: @arturios can you please give me an example!!

Comment: @M. Kamal If you are dealing with numbers the 0 will be interpreted as false which is a problem.

// In this case the value will be undefined wich is ok
var value;
if (!value) {
 console.log("value is false, undefined or empty")
}

// In this case value is set as 0, this is the problem of using this approach when you deal with number
value = 0;
if (!value) {
 console.log("value is false, undefined or empty")
}

Comment: @arturios But 0 is already a falsy value in JavaScript !! so what is the point here?

Comment: Yes i understand but the question refers only to undefined and null, but now i look that you put the comment of false also.

Comment: For what it's worth: I would have written the update as `typeof sth !== 'undefined' && sth !== null`. As tests are executed from left to right, I had an error with an undefined `sth` for the test `sth !== null`

Comment: @Al-un nope, see it in action [here](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=%2F%2F%20it's%20undefined.%0D%0Aconst%20something%20%3D%20undefined%0D%0A%0D%0Aif%20(something%20!%3D%3D%20null%20%26%26%20typeof%20something%20!%3D%3D%20'undefined')%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%2F%2F%20your%20logic%20here...%0D%0A%7D%20else%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20console.log('NOPE%2C%20no%20errors!')%0D%0A%7D)

Comment: the updated version is wrong. The first thing to check should be undefined... like:
`if(typeof something !== 'undefined' && something !== null){...}`

Answer (score 15):

```
if(data){}
```

it's mean !data

- null
- undefined
- false
- ....

Comment: And if data is of boolean type?

Comment: can you combine two variables eg. if(value1 && value2) to check if both of them are undefined ?

Comment: @ianstigator A boolean can be evaluated as `true` or `false` only. If you have a boolean with a `null` assignation or an `undefined` value, in both cases the value will be evaluated as `false`.

Comment: This fails when data is a boolean value

Answer (score 10):

**UPDATE (Sept 4, 2020)**

You can now use the `??` operator to validate `null` and `undefined` "values" and set a default value. For example:

```js
const foo = null;
const bar = foo ?? 'exampleValue';
console.log(bar); // This will print 'exampleValue' due to the value condition of the foo constant, in this case, a null value
```

---

As a verbose way, if you want to compare *null* and *undefined* values **ONLY**, use the following example code for reference:

```js
const incomingValue : string = undefined;
const somethingToCompare : string = incomingValue; // If the line above is not declared, TypeScript will return an excepion

if (somethingToCompare == (undefined || null)) {
  console.log(`Incoming value is: ${somethingToCompare}`);
}
```

If `incomingValue` is not declared, TypeScript should return an exception. If this is declared but not defined, the `console.log()` will return "Incoming value is: undefined". Note we are not using the strict equals operator.

The "correct" way (check the other answers for details), if the `incomingValue` is not a `boolean` type, just evaluate if its value is true, this will be evaluated according to the constant/variable type. A `true` string have to be defined explicitly as string using the `= ''` assignation. If not, it will be evaluated as `false`. Let's check this case using the same context:

```js
const incomingValue : string = undefined;
const somethingToCompare0 : string = 'Trumpet';
const somethingToCompare1 : string = incomingValue;

if (somethingToCompare0) {
  console.log(`somethingToCompare0 is: ${somethingToCompare0}`); // Will return "somethingToCompare0 is: Trumpet"
}

// Now, we will evaluate the second constant
if (somethingToCompare1) {
  console.log(`somethingToCompare1 is: ${somethingToCompare1}`); // Launched if incomingValue is defined
} else {
  console.log(`somethingToCompare1 is: ${somethingToCompare1}`); // Launched if incomingValue is undefined. Will return "somethingToCompare1 is: undefined"
}
```

Comment: somethingToCompare == (undefined || null).                    

(undefined || null) resolves to null, so it's a loose comparison between somethingToCompare and null

Comment: @carlosvini Sure, the point of the comparison is to be verbose and provide a code for reference. That's the reason of the non-strict equals comparison. The purpose of the answer is to be clear and explicative. I'll edit the text to avoid confusion

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. The code is not verbose or explicit, it is confusing at best and plain wrong at worst. The code `a == (b || c)` is the **not** the same as `a == b || a == c`, instead it will evaluate `b || c` (in this case to `c` since `b` is falsy in your example) and then compare that against `a`.

Answer (score 8):

If you want to pass `tslint` without setting `strict-boolean-expressions` to `allow-null-union` or `allow-undefined-union`, you need to use `isNullOrUndefined` from `node`'s `util` module or roll your own:

```
// tslint:disable:no-null-keyword
export const isNullOrUndefined =
  <T>(obj: T | null | undefined): obj is null | undefined => {
    return typeof obj === "undefined" || obj === null;
  };
// tslint:enable:no-null-keyword
```

Not exactly syntactic sugar but useful when your tslint rules are strict.

Answer (score 7):

If you are using TypeScript, it is a better approach to let the compiler check for nulls and undefineds (or the possibility thereof), rather than checking for them at run-time. (If you do want to check at run-time, then as many answers indicate, just use `value == null`).

Use the compile option [`strictNullChecks`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-0.html) to tell the compiler to choke on possible null or undefined values. If you set this option, and then there is a situation where you **do** want to allow null and undefined, you can define the type as `Type | null | undefined`.

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way is to use:

`import { isNullOrUndefined } from 'util';`

and than:

`if (!isNullOrUndefined(foo))`

Comment: Works great here

Comment: From the function docs: deprecated since v4.0.0 - use `value === null || value === undefined` instead.

Comment: @Aleksei that's ironic

Answer (score 2):

We use a helper `hasValue` that both checks for nulls/undefined and ensures via TypeScript that unnecessary checks are not performed. (The latter is similar to how TS would complain about `if ("a" === undefined)`, since it is always false).

Using this consistently is always safe, unlike `!val` which matches empty strings, zero, etc.  It also avoid the use of fuzzy `==` matching which is almost always a bad practice - no need to introduce an exception.

```
type NullPart<T> = T & (null | undefined);

// Ensures unnecessary checks aren't performed - only a valid call if 
// value could be nullable *and* could be non-nullable
type MustBeAmbiguouslyNullable<T> = NullPart<T> extends never
  ? never
  : NonNullable<T> extends never
  ? never
  : T;

export function hasValue<T>(
  value: MustBeAmbiguouslyNullable<T>,
): value is NonNullable<MustBeAmbiguouslyNullable<T>> {
  return (value as unknown) !== undefined && (value as unknown) !== null;
}

export function hasValueFn<T, A>(
  value: MustBeAmbiguouslyNullable<T>,
  thenFn: (value: NonNullable<T>) => A,
): A | undefined {
  // Undefined matches .? syntax result
  return hasValue(value) ? thenFn(value) : undefined;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

May be to late! but you can use `??` operator in **typescript**.
see https://mariusschulz.com/blog/nullish-coalescing-the-operator-in-typescript

Answer (score 2):

It can be done like this:

```
 // value is the value which you want to check
 [undefined, null].includes(value)
```

Answer (score 1):

Late to join this thread but I find this JavaScript hack very handy in checking whether a value is undefined

```
 if(typeof(something) === 'undefined'){
   // Yes this is undefined
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this easily with a ternary operator and the new nullish coalesce operator.

First: check to see if it is true using the ternary. If so return false so the if statement does not run.

Second: because you now know the value is falsey, you can use the nullish coalesce operator to return true if it is nullish. Since it will return itself for any other value, if it is not nullish it will fail the if statement correctly.

```js
let x = true;
console.log("starting tests")

if (x?false:x ?? true){
  console.log(x,"is nullish")
}

x = false
if (x?false:x ?? true){
  console.log(x,"is nullish")
}

x = 0;
if (x?false:x ?? true){
  console.log(x,"is nullish")
}

x=1;
if (x?false:x ?? true){
  console.log(x,"is nullish")
}

x="";
if (x?false:x ?? true){
  console.log(x,"is nullish")
}

x="hello world";
if (x?false:x ?? true){
  console.log(x,"is nullish")
}

x=null;
if (x?false:x ?? true){
  console.log(x,"is nullish")
}

x=undefined;
if (x?false:x ?? true){
  console.log(x,"is nullish")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
if(x === undefined)
```

Answer (score 0):

All,

The answer with the most votes, does not really work if you are working with an object. In that case, if a property is not present, the check will not work. And that was the issue in our case: see this sample:

```
var x =
{ name: "Homer", LastName: "Simpson" };

var y =
{ name: "Marge"} ;

var z =
{ name: "Bart" , LastName: undefined} ;

var a =
{ name: "Lisa" , LastName: ""} ;

var hasLastNameX = x.LastName != null;
var hasLastNameY = y.LastName != null;
var hasLastNameZ = z.LastName != null;
var hasLastNameA = a.LastName != null;



alert (hasLastNameX + ' ' + hasLastNameY + ' ' + hasLastNameZ + ' ' + hasLastNameA);

var hasLastNameXX = x.LastName !== null;
var hasLastNameYY = y.LastName !== null;
var hasLastNameZZ = z.LastName !== null;
var hasLastNameAA = a.LastName !== null;

alert (hasLastNameXX + ' ' + hasLastNameYY + ' ' + hasLastNameZZ + ' ' + hasLastNameAA);
```

Outcome:

```
true , false, false , true (in case of !=)
true , true, true, true (in case of !==) => so in this sample not the correct answer
```

plunkr link: https://plnkr.co/edit/BJpVHD95FhKlpHp1skUE

Comment: This is not good test. None of those values are *strictly* `null`. Try this: https://plnkr.co/edit/NfiVnQNes1p8PvXd1fCG?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

Since TypeScript is a typed superset of ES6 JavaScript. And lodash are a library of javascript.

Using lodash to checks if value is null or undefined can be done using `_.isNil()`.

```
_.isNil(value)
```

#### Arguments

**value** (*): The value to check.

#### Returns

**(boolean)**: Returns true if value is nullish, else false.

#### Example

```
_.isNil(null);
// => true

_.isNil(void 0);
// => true

_.isNil(NaN);
// => false
```

#### Link

[Lodash Docs](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#isNil)

Comment: Why this method are -2 ?
Lodash is not good with type script ?

Answer (score 0):

A faster and shorter notation for `null` checks can be:

```
value == null ? "UNDEFINED" : value
```

This line is equivalent to:

```
if(value == null) {
       console.log("UNDEFINED")
} else {
    console.log(value)
}
```

Especially when you have a lot of `null` check it is a nice short notation.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue and some of the answer work just fine for `JS` but not for `TS` here is the reason.

```
//JS
let couldBeNullOrUndefined;
if(couldBeNullOrUndefined == null) {
  console.log('null OR undefined', couldBeNullOrUndefined);
} else {
  console.log('Has some value', couldBeNullOrUndefined);
}
```

That is all good as JS has no Types

```
//TS
let couldBeNullOrUndefined?: string | null; // THIS NEEDS TO BE TYPED AS undefined || null || Type(string)

if(couldBeNullOrUndefined === null) { // TS should always use strict-check
  console.log('null OR undefined', couldBeNullOrUndefined);
} else {
  console.log('Has some value', couldBeNullOrUndefined);
}
```

In TS if the variable wasn't defined with `null` when you try to check for that `null` the `tslint` | compiler will complain.

```
//tslint.json
...
"triple-equals":[true],
...
```

```
 let couldBeNullOrUndefined?: string; // to fix it add | null

 Types of property 'couldBeNullOrUndefined' are incompatible.
      Type 'string | null' is not assignable to type 'string | undefined'.
        Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'string | undefined'.
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually I do the  juggling-check as Fenton already [discussed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28984306/4812980). 
To make it more readable, you can use [isNil](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#isNil) from ramda.

```
import * as isNil from 'ramda/src/isNil';

totalAmount = isNil(totalAmount ) ? 0 : totalAmount ;
```

Answer (score 0):

careful if you're using local storage, you can end up with the string undefined rather than the value undefined:

```
localStorage.setItem('mykey',JSON.stringify(undefined));
localStorage.getItem('mykey') === "undefined"
true
```

People may find this useful: https://github.com/angular/components/blob/master/src/cdk/coercion/boolean-property.spec.ts

```
/**
 * @license
 * Copyright Google LLC All Rights Reserved.
 *
 * Use of this source code is governed by an MIT-style license that can be
 * found in the LICENSE file at https://angular.io/license
 */

/** Coerces a data-bound value (typically a string) to a boolean. */
export function coerceBooleanProperty(value: any): boolean {
  return value != null && `${value}` !== 'false';
}

import {coerceBooleanProperty} from './boolean-property';

describe('coerceBooleanProperty', () => {

  it('should coerce undefined to false', () => {
    expect(coerceBooleanProperty(undefined)).toBe(false);
  });

  it('should coerce null to false', () => {
    expect(coerceBooleanProperty(null)).toBe(false);
  });

  it('should coerce the empty string to true', () => {
    expect(coerceBooleanProperty('')).toBe(true);
  });

  it('should coerce zero to true', () => {
    expect(coerceBooleanProperty(0)).toBe(true);
  });

  it('should coerce the string "false" to false', () => {
    expect(coerceBooleanProperty('false')).toBe(false);
  });

  it('should coerce the boolean false to false', () => {
    expect(coerceBooleanProperty(false)).toBe(false);
  });

  it('should coerce the boolean true to true', () => {
    expect(coerceBooleanProperty(true)).toBe(true);
  });

  it('should coerce the string "true" to true', () => {
    expect(coerceBooleanProperty('true')).toBe(true);
  });

  it('should coerce an arbitrary string to true', () => {
    expect(coerceBooleanProperty('pink')).toBe(true);
  });

  it('should coerce an object to true', () => {
    expect(coerceBooleanProperty({})).toBe(true);
  });

  it('should coerce an array to true', () => {
    expect(coerceBooleanProperty([])).toBe(true);
  });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

You could use:

```
if (!!variable) {}
```

it equals writting

```
it (variable != null && variable != undefined) {}
```

Comment: This would omit any value that *could* be valid that resolves to false when double-negated, such as 0 or an empty string.

Answer (score -8):

I always write it like this:

```
var foo:string;

if(!foo){
   foo="something";    
}
```

This will work fine and I think it's very readable.

Comment: Wouldn't work for numbers because `0` also passes the `!foo` test.

Comment: Does not work for booleans either, where `undefined` is different than `false`. This is very common with optional boolean function parameters, where you should use the common JavaScript approach: `function fn(flag?: boolean) { if (typeof flag === "undefined") flag = true; /* set default value */ }`

Comment: Seems to work ok for booleans: `var isTrue;      
        if(isTrue)//skips, 
        if(!isTrue)// enters
        if(isTrue === undefined)//enters`. Also tried it in typescript with `var isTrue:boolean` which was undefined, and the same if checks. @Gingi, is there something different about what you tried and what I tried?