# Is there a consistent way to test for undefined and null in typescript 2.0?

Tags: typescript2.0

So, I have several checks like this in my code:

```
if (callerParam != undefined || callerParam != null)
```

I now upgraded to Typescript 2.0 and Visual Studio is telling 'Cannot resolve symbol 'undefined''.

But the compare to null is just fine.

So I guess I can go change all my compares to be like this:

```
if (typeof callerParam !== 'undefined' || callerParam != null)
```

and the intellisense is OK with that.

But it seems inconsistent.

**Is there a way to get my consistant, happy, world back?**

And, why is undefined not valid anymore?  And yet it is valid javascript right?

Comment: Your answer could be found here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28975896/is-there-a-dedicated-function-to-check-null-and-undefined-in-typescript

Comment: @AlfMoh - Thanks for directing me!