# What coerces from a null compare in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

If I have this JavaScript

```
var someVar = someOtherVar == null;
```

**What values of `someOtherVar` will cause `someVar` to be true?**

**Note:** From what I have read, if `someOtherVar` is `undefined` then `someVar` will be true.  But I am changing a lot of my code to use this style of comparison, and I want to be sure that nothing else will result in a *truthy* statement (besides `null` and `undefined`).

Comment: From my understanding you are correct in saying that undefined and null are the only two values that will result in a truthy value here.

Comment: Since most linters will not like `someOtherVar == null`, why not go the explicit route and not have to worry about "other values"? `var someVar = (someOtherVar === null || someOtherVar === undefined)`

Comment: @gforce301 - because I am using typescript 2.0 and for some reason beyond my understanding, I can't do a compare to undefined anymore...  ( see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43594261/is-there-a-consistent-way-to-test-for-undefined-and-null-in-typescript-2-0 for details)

Comment: @Vaccano I see. I have had to do this before: `var undefined;` and then you can do `if (callerParam != undefined || callerParam != null)`

Comment: Doesn't the [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28975896/is-there-a-dedicated-function-to-check-null-and-undefined-in-typescript) given for your previous question answer this? I don't understand why you're asking basically the same thing again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> What values of `someOtherVar` will cause `someVar` to be `true`?

Only `null` and `undefined`.

[The algorithm in the spec is relatively straight forward](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/#sec-abstract-equality-comparison):

> 1. If `Type(x)` is the same as `Type(y)`, then     Return the result of performing [Strict Equality Comparison `x === y`](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/#sec-strict-equality-comparison).
> 2. If `x` is **null** and `y` is **undefined**, return **true**.
> 3. If `x` is **undefined** and `y` is **null**, return **true**.
> 4. If `Type(x)` is Number and `Type(y)` is String, return the result of the comparison `x == ToNumber(y)`.
> 5. If `Type(x)` is String and `Type(y)` is Number, return the result of the comparison `ToNumber(x) == y`.
> 6. If `Type(x)` is Boolean, return the result of the comparison `ToNumber(x) == y`.
> 7. If `Type(y)` is Boolean, return the result of the comparison `x == ToNumber(y)`.
> 8. If `Type(x)` is either String, Number, or Symbol and `Type(y)` is Object, return the result of the comparison `x == ToPrimitive(y)`.
> 9. If `Type(x)` is Object and `Type(y)` is either String, Number, or Symbol, return the result of the comparison `ToPrimitive(x) == y`.
> 10. Return **false**.

Step 1 handles the case `null == null`. Step 2 and 3 handle the cases `null == undefined` and `undefined == null`. Step 6 and 7 handle the cases where the other value is a boolean, so then you end up comparing a number against `null`. Since `null` is not an object, number, string, boolean or symbol, non of the other steps apply, so `false` is returned (step 10).

---

> What coerces from a null compare in JavaScript?

Only if the other value is a *boolean* it would be coerced to a *number*, so you end up comparing either `0 == null` or `1 == null`, both of which are `false`.

In all other case, no type coercion is happening (nothing is coerced to `null` and `null` is not coerced to any other data type).

Comment: Solid answer.  Love it when answers quote the spec!

Answer (score 1):

Looks like only `null` and `undefined` indeed:

```js
const arr = ['string', true, false, 0, null, undefined, NaN, {}, [], 4, -1, -0];

const r = arr.map((e,i) => {
    return { i, e, bool: e == null }
}).filter(e => e.bool);

// return elements which result in 'null'
// i: index inside initial array 'arr'

console.log(JSON.stringify(r, null, 2));
```