# Check if variable is defined in Typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

**I'm trying to check if a variable is undefined using typescript** but am not having any luck.

I am currently trying

```
if (typeof variablename !== 'undefined') { /*do something here*/ }
```

but for some reason the compiler always gives me the error

```
Cannot find name 'variablename'
```

I can pull up the browser console and paste the above code and it works as expected. The file containing the `undefined` check exists in a file that is not imported by any other JS/TS file.

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43716263/how-to-check-undefined-in-typescript

Comment: Is it really a browser error, or rather a typescript compile error? What does the compiled javascript look like?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to check undefined in Typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43716263/how-to-check-undefined-in-typescript)

Comment: you can actually do simply `if (variablename !== undefined)` for the same effect. as for your question exactly, gonna need more code

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The TypeScript compiler won't let you access a variable it doesn't know about, since most of the time such accesses are errors.

If you want the compiler to believe that such a variable is in scope, you could [`declare` it](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/by-example.html#global-variables) first:

```
declare var variablename: string | undefined;
if (typeof variablename !== 'undefined') { /*do something here*/ }
```

That doesn't change the emitted JavaScript at all. It just tells the compiler to act as if there is a `var` named `variablename` in scope whose type is `string | undefined` (in your use case it might be some type other than `string` but I needed an example).  In other words, it assumes that your JavaScript will run in a context where `variablename` of such a type is around.

This isn't *exactly* what you want, since it's possible at runtime that there is no such variable.  Unfortunately there's no way to tell the compiler that the variable *might be* in scope and that `typeof` can be used to check it.  Variables are either in scope (and you can access them) or they're not (and you can't). There was a proposal at [microsoft/TypeScript#23602](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/23602) to have a way to conditionally declare variables, but nothing came of it.  Declaring the variable as definitely-existing but of a type with `| undefined` in it is as close as you can get, I think.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.1.3#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEA3WTYEsoCMIgHZQFsQAueAZwBcY1cBzeAH3gFddQAzGkYAbgFgAUGnbwAFBQCeABxAB7EcmpYc+IvACEAXk3wA5Kw5dgugJTwA3vAD0AKmCzysohQAWNei5BwbV+AF8gA)