# Typescript + webpack: Check for variable that is not defined in Node, but defined in Browser

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, webpack, local-storage

I am trying to write a package for server and client use with as little modification as needed.

Some libs are part of Node but not included in a browser, others are available in a browser but not in Node.

Using https://github.com/lmaccherone/node-localstorage for example, I want to `require` the library when on Node, but in a browser, localStorage is already available.

I would like to check whether `localStorage` is available with a declare statement found in https://stackoverflow.com/a/65755447/2875404 so it looks like that:

```
declare var localStorage: any | undefined;

if (typeof localStorage === "undefined" || localStorage === null) {
    console.log("need to use Node localStorage")
    var LocalStorage = require('node-localstorage').LocalStorage;
    var localStorage = new LocalStorage('./localStorage');
  } else {
    console.log("using Browser localStorage")
  }
```

After wrapping up the package in webpack and, for a test, running it in a Chrome snippet, the `"need to use Node localStorage"` message pops up in console. If I manually edit the webpack'd code to `console.log(localStorage)` it actually does print the localStorage (so it must be there) - additionally, when I remove the whole `if (typeof...` block, the code accessing `localStorage` seems to run just fine.

What exactly do I need to do to make this "hybrid decision" function work? Can this have to do with webpack somehow putting things into a "deeper" scope that doesn't have access to window variables such as localStorage? But why is it possible to print and interact with the class then? I'm confused.

Comment: Check for `window` global instead?

Comment: @Dominik you are the best.  I check for window and access the variable as window.localStorage now. Write as answer please so I can tick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said in the comment, you could use the global `window` to check if you're in browser context:

```js
declare var localStorage: any | undefined;

if (typeof window === 'undefined') {
    console.log("need to use Node localStorage")
    var LocalStorage = require('node-localstorage').LocalStorage;
    var localStorage = new LocalStorage('./localStorage');
} else {
    console.log("using Browser localStorage")
}
```