# Jasmine: Matcher to be different from undefined and diferent from null (!= undefined and != null)

Tags: unit-testing, jasmine

I had notice that if I write the expect `expect(null).toBeDefined();`, the test will be passed, because the jasmine considers that null is a object difined but without any value.

My question is that if there is a matcher that evaluates if the object is diferent that `undefined` and `null` at the same time.

Comment: If it is an object, you can use `toBeFalsy`, since it won't compare it to 0, `''`, or NaN. For more information, see the [documentation about falsy values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use `.toEqual()`:

```
expect(context).not.toEqual(null);
```

In Javascript `undefined == null` is `true`, so this test will exclude both `undefined` and `null`.

Comment: Error: Expected undefined to equal null.

Comment: @AliAdravi That's odd. I thought I had tested this at the time but Jasmine explicitly checks whether either value being compared is `null` and if so uses `===`. I would delete this answer but can't delete accepted posts. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 5):

## Fails if context is null or undefined. This better way for checking existing

```
expect(context).toEqual(jasmine.anything());
```

Example:

```js
  fit(`jasmine.anything()`, () => {
    const undef = undefined;
    const nul = null;
    const foo = 'bar';
    const zero = 0;
    const nonZero = 1;

    expect(undef).toEqual(jasmine.anything()); // fail
    expect(nul).toEqual(jasmine.anything()); // fail
    expect(foo).toEqual(jasmine.anything()); // pass
    expect(zero).toEqual(jasmine.anything()); // pass
    expect(nonZero).toEqual(jasmine.anything()); // pass

    expect(undef).not.toEqual(jasmine.anything()); // pass
    expect(nul).not.toEqual(jasmine.anything()); // pass
    expect(foo).not.toEqual(jasmine.anything()); // fail
    expect(zero).not.toEqual(jasmine.anything()); // fail
    expect(nonZero).not.toEqual(jasmine.anything()); // fail
  });
```

Comment: This should be marked as the correct answer. I've created a github issue to make this a built-in matcher: https://github.com/jasmine/jasmine/issues/2018

Answer (score 1):

The only way that I find out was to evaluate if is `undefined` and if is not `null` in diferent statements like follows:

```
expect(context).toBeDefined();
expect(context).not.toBeNull();
```

But this not really answer my question.

Comment: was my answer helpful?

Answer (score 0):

So as far as I understand you can use the [juggling-check](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28975896/is-there-a-way-to-check-for-both-null-and-undefined/28984306#28984306) to check for both null and undefined.

```
let foo;
console.log(foo == null); // returns true when foo is undefined

let bar = null;
console.log (bar == null); // returns true when bar is null
```

Then I have been doing this with the jasmine expect

```
expect(foo == null).toBe(true);  // returns true when foo is null or undefined
```

It would be really great if we could do this (but you can't as far as I know).

```
expect(foo).toBeNullOrUndefined() // How cool would that be! :-)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my approach. I think it's descriptive.

```js
 expect(![null, undefined].includes(myValue))
    .withContext('myValue should not be null or undefined')
    .toEqual(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

I resorted to `expect(myValue || undefined).toBeDefined()`, so a possible `null` would become `undefined` which then fails the condition as desired.