# what is the alternative for the util.isNullOrUndefined(object) in the Util module ? Angular 7

Tags: angular, module

util.isNullOrUndefined(object) has been depreciated and I cannot find any alternative for it. Can someone point out a feasible alternative for it?

```
if (isNullOrUndefined(this.activeAppKey) || this.activeAppKey.trim().length === 0) {
  this.activeAppKey = sessionStorage.getItem(AppConstants.APP_KEY);
}
```

Comment: `if (!this.activeAppKey || this.activeAppKey.trim().length === 0) {
  this.activeAppKey = sessionStorage.getItem(AppConstants.APP_KEY);
}`

Answer (score 8):

import it from ['is-what'](https://www.npmjs.com/package/is-what)

so,

> import { isUndefined, isNullOrUndefined } from 'util';

will become,

> import { isUndefined, isNullOrUndefined } from 'is-what';

Answer (score 5):

Why not simply create you own:

```
export function isNullOrUndefined(value: any) {
    return value === null || value === undefined;
}
```

Lets say you create a tools.ts file and write the above code:

You can use it in your component as follows :

```
import { isNullOrUndefined } from 'tools';
```

The above code will work no changes there. Plus it will reusable

Answer (score 4):

try using `!` operator.

```
if (!this.activeAppKey) {
  this.activeAppKey = sessionStorage.getItem(AppConstants.APP_KEY);
}
```

Comment: Using `!` operator can cause some troubles, when variable is number 0, empty string etc. See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28975896/is-there-a-dedicated-function-to-check-null-and-undefined-in-typescript

Comment: it produces errors for codes like ` if (!isNullOrUndefined(user.customRoles[this.activeAppKey])) {
          ui.role = user.customRoles[this.activeAppKey].roleKey;
        }`

Comment: Have you checked user itself is null?

Comment: Might be a good idea to explain [Javascript truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy).

Comment: you can't use `!` operator. because this will not allow you to enter in if condition body for this.activeAppKey value is `false` instead if `null` or `undefined`.

Comment: Simply using `this.activeAppKey != null` would be enough. It's simple to type and read, and covers both `null` and `undefined`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `isNullOrUndefined` function from the [core-util-is](https://www.npmjs.com/package/core-util-is) npm package.

It was deprecated from nodejs core because behaviour or api changes on these functions could break a lot of existing code without notifying the users. In a npm package, using semver, only a major version bump can break api/behaviour. A lot safer this way.

Comment: bump for being the actual explanation for the deprecation. and the OP was asking for a feasible alternative, which you provide.

and also it's good to understand the reason since now i am not about to go back and my brain for an additional ten minutes trying to figure out a good way to do it elsewise, so cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Using a double equals on a `null` checks for `null` and `undefined` exclusively

`if (this.activeAppKey == null || this.activeAppKey.trim().length === 0)`

```
null == undefined // true
null == null      // true
null == 0         // false
null == ""        // false
null == false     // false
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
if (this.activeAppKey === null || this.activeAppKey === undefined || this.activeAppKey.trim().length === 0) {
  this.activeAppKey = sessionStorage.getItem(AppConstants.APP_KEY);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would go for this approach. Create some util class and add this as a static method.

```
export class Util {
  static isNullOrUndefined<T>(obj: T | null | undefined): obj is null | undefined {
    return typeof obj === 'undefined' || obj === null;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From NodeJs reference [https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#utilisnullorundefinedobject] :

> Deprecated: Use `value === undefined || value === null` instead.

This makes the answer given by super IT guy above correct (https://stackoverflow.com/a/56138823/6757814)