# Property `data` does not exist on Type <void> | AxiosHttpResponse<any>

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, axios

I have a promise, that I use in order to setState, when I fetch Data for a specific User. Below is the code for that:

```
getUserUsername = (): string => {
    const { match } = this.props;
    return match.params.username;
  };

  onFetchUser = () =>
    getUser(this.getUserUsername())
      .then(username => {
        if (this.hasBeenMounted) {
          this.setState({
            user: username.data // The error is here.
          });
        }
      })
      .catch((errorResponse: HttpResponseObj | null = null) => {
        if (this.hasBeenMounted) {
          this.setState({
            isLoading: false,
            user: null,
            errorMessage: errorResponse
          });
        }
      });
```

But I get this TS error saying:

```
Property 'data' does not exist on type 'void | AxiosResponse<IUser>'.
  Property 'data' does not exist on type 'void'.ts(2339)
---
any
```

The `getUser()`, is a service that I use and the code for it is here:

```
export const getUser = (username: string, initialOptions = {}): HttpResponse<IUser> => {
  const options = {
    method: httpMethod.GET,
    url: endpoint.GET_USER(username)
  };
  return Instance(options, lensesOptions);
};
```

The code for the HttpResponse is here:

```
export interface HttpResponse<T> extends Promise<void | AxiosResponse<T>> {}
```

I tried something like:

```
      .then((username): HttpResponse<any> => { // Doesn't work though
        if (this.hasBeenMounted) {
          this.setState({
            user: username.data
          });
        }
      })
```

Here is the Axios Interface:

```
export interface AxiosResponse<T = any>  {
  data: T;
  status: number;
  statusText: string;
  headers: any;
  config: AxiosRequestConfig;
  request?: any;
}
```

Can you please explain to me what is the problem. I go to axios Interface and I see it `data`, as well as the `generic` there no problem.. Thank you!!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to check the type of `username` before try to use it because the function is returning two values with different properties (void and AxiosResponse)

So you have to check like this:

```
  .then(username => {
    // Check if it is not void
    if (this.hasBeenMounted && username ) { 
      this.setState({
        user: username.data
      });
    }
  })
```

Comment: Ok, both of them worked. One question though. Is there any difference between, the existing answer and the one you posted before.
`username !== undefined && username.data` !== `typeof username !== 'undefined'`.

Comment: See my latest update. Username could be `null` or `undefined` because `void` is a [supertype](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#void) of them. So, if you just check the username value [it evaluates `null` and `undefined`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44017547/2389232) among others.

Don't use my previous answer (`typeof username !== 'undefined'`) because I took advantage of a possible typescript bug. I have created a [question to understand it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55360626/typescript-property-property-does-not-exist-on-type-void-isample).