# What's the best way to assert not null or not undefined in assert in node.js unit test?

Tags: node.js

Node has build in assert,
https://nodejs.org/api/assert.html

i want to assert the return value is valid, not these cases:

```
null
undefined
NaN
empty string ("")
0
false
```

in dev code i can just do

```
if (value)
```

but in unit test, what's the assert method ?
Again i'm using the native assert from node.js

Thanks !

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to check for both \`null\` and \`undefined\`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28975896/is-there-a-way-to-check-for-both-null-and-undefined)

Comment: not dup, i'm talking about unit test

Comment: It is a duplicate. you simply put that in your assertion.

Comment: sigh, it cannot be a dup. If i put that piece of code in our unit test, it will do the job, but won't pass our code review. Almost all companies require mocha/assert/chai etc frameworks, the code needs to be consistent.

Comment: In that case, you're just asking an opinion-based question? That other question solves the technical problem, if you're just looking for someone to validate what your code reviews demand, then that's just an opinion, and not really a question for StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

assert.ok(val) ?

would this be the simpliest way ?

Comment: Nope, `assert.ok(0)` results in an `AssertionError` ([docs](https://nodejs.org/api/assert.html#assert_assert_ok_value_message))

Comment: if that case, you can do assert.ok(val === 0);

Comment: Not quite, that would not catch `false`