# Typescript: test for Nan, null and undefined only

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I like to use the `!!` in Javascript to ensure that a variable is set and that no error will be thrown.

However today I have a variable with `0` value that is valid for me. I need to ensure that it is not NaN nor undefined, is there really no **short** way to do it without the boring `if (variable !== NaN && variable !== undefined`?

If that may help, I am using angular.

Thx.

Comment: undefined and NaN are both falsy values, so you can use `if (variable) { }`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to check for both \`null\` and \`undefined\`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28975896/is-there-a-way-to-check-for-both-null-and-undefined)

Comment: @JakubJanik, it will return false for 0 also, which is not desired here.

Comment: FYI, `variable !== NaN` will **always** be true, because `NaN != NaN`. To properly check for `NaN` you need to use `isNaN()`.

Comment: Based on the already provided answers, you could use `if (variable != null && !isNaN(variable))`. As far as I know, this will be the shortest way to implement your logic.

Comment: I would also watch for the `undefined` value with a: `if (variable != undefined && variable != null && !isNaN(variable))`

Comment: Depending on its content a non empty array can still be a `NaN` value. To guard against this: `&& (Array.isArray(value) || !isNaN(value)`

Answer (score 6):

```
const a = 'value';

if (isNaN(a) || a === null) {
    console.log('a is NaN or null, undefined');
} else {
    // business logic ;)
}
```

Handle `null` in addition, because `isNaN(null) === false`.

Comment: You correctly use `a == null` instead of `a === null` here to check for both `null` and `undefined`. Nice.

Comment: `a == null` is impossible working in a team, one might think I forgot it and add a `=` this is not readable at all. Moreover tslint might reject it.

Comment: @Rolintocour, with default angular tslint configuration it works well. Otherwise, you should do smth like this: `a === null || a === undefined'. But I prefer to make it shorter.

Answer (score 3):

You can use isNan. It will return `true` for `undefined` and `NAN` value but not for `ZERO`.

```
const variable = undefined;

 if(isNaN(variable)){
   console.log('I am undefined / NAN'); 
 }else{
   console.log('I am something / zero');
}
```

Comment: You SHOULD use `isNan()`. ;) You cannot directly use `NaN` in comparisons. The expression `NaN === NaN` will always return `false`.

Comment: In typescript, the `isNaN()` function does not accept the `undefined` argument. The error message is: `Argument of type 'undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'number'.`

Comment: @Stephane, use isNaN(Number(YOURVARIABLEHERE))

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to check for `undefined, null, NaN` is

```js
if(a == null || Number.isNaN(a)) {
  // we did it!
}
```

please notice the use of `Number.isNaN` instead of just `isNaN`.
If you did use just `isNaN` then your check will not do what you want for values like strings or empty object

```js
if(a == null || isNaN(a)) {
  // {} comes in because `isNaN({})` is `true`
  // strings that can't be coerced into numbers 
  // some other funny things
}
```

Read more at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN)