# Check AND condition with Boolean and Object. Check if object is defined

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have the following:

```
let user: UserModel = getUser();

let active: Boolean = getStatus();
```

I tried the following condition:

```
if (active && user && user.claims && { Extra Condition using user.claims } ) {

}
```

I need `active` to be `true` and then check a condition with `user.claims`.

But before I need to be sure that `user` and `user.claims` are defined.

However, I am getting two errors:

```
Type 'UserModel' is not assignable to type 'boolean'

Type 'Claim[]' is not assignable to type 'boolean'
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: `Boolean` is the wrong type. It is `boolean`. Also, stop annotating local variables especially, simple ones, when you can infer the types them from their initializer. It's the poor practice and interferes with type inference and control flow analysis

Comment: You could simplify it to `active && user?.claims?.extraCondition`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`user != null && user.claims != null` is what you want. You can also refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28975896/is-there-a-way-to-check-for-both-null-and-undefined) answer.