# how to checking control undefined value in angular

Tags: angular

i am bigginer in angular,my form in html is :

```
<mat-card  style="padding:20px;margin:30px;text-align: right;">
  <mat-card-header>
    <mat-card-title>title</mat-card-title>
  </mat-card-header>
   <mat-card-content style="width: 150px; display: contents;" [formGroup]="formGroupContent">
          <div>
          <mat-form-field class = "tp-full-width" style="padding-left: 20px;">
              <input #amvalcode formControlName="equiid" matInput placeholder = "code" value = "">
          </mat-form-field>
        </mat-card-content>
  <mat-card-actions >
          <button mat-raised-button color="accent" type="button" style="width:200px;" 
          (click)="add_equi(captioncode.selected.value.id)">add</button>
  </mat-card-actions>
```

and in type script :

```
    add_equi(CaptionCode){
        if (this.formGroupContent.controls['equiid']?.value === undefined){
                    console.log("undefined value");
        }else{
                    console.log("has value");
         }
    }
```

equiid is formControlName ,but when in equiid is null i recive

```
Cannot read property 'value' of undefined
```

Comment: Simply check if this.formGroupContent.controls['equiid'] is null?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to check for both \`null\` and \`undefined\`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28975896/is-there-a-way-to-check-for-both-null-and-undefined)

Comment: The error is not showing the line it's been dores? Also, captioncode.selected in your HTML is defined?

Comment: yes ,it work where has value but when no value in control i recive error